# POSTFIX: Can Not Send Mail To Other Domains Using Mail Client

Tags: 16.04, thunderbird, postfix, mail, email-client

I've configured POSTFIX using [Ubuntu Help's Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixBasicSetupHowto).
I can send and receive mails to any domain while I am using `ssh`, but when I use mail clients (like Thunderbird or iPhone Mail) I can just send mails through my own domain but no Gmail or any other domain.
I've looked for solutions, found these links but didn't answer:

[can't send emails to gmail accounts from postfix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765205/cant-send-emails-to-gmail-accounts-from-postfix)

[I am failing to send mail to a Gmail address using Postfix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21441/i-am-failing-to-send-mail-to-a-gmail-address-using-postfix)

Here is my `main.cf`:

```
      # See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


  # Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
  # line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
  # is /etc/mailname.
  #myorigin = /etc/mailname

  smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
  biff = no

  # appending .domain is the MUA's job.
  append_dot_mydomain = no

  # Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
  #delay_warning_time = 4h

  readme_directory = no

  # TLS parameters
  smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
  smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
  smtpd_use_tls=yes
  smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
  smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

  # See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
  # information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

  smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
  myhostname = webgo.ir
  alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
  alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
  myorigin = /etc/mailname
  mydestination = webgo.ir, localhost.localdomain, localhost
  relayhost = 
  mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 137.74.154.133/32
  mailbox_command = 
  mailbox_size_limit = 0
  recipient_delimiter = +
  inet_interfaces = all
  inet_protocols = all
  home_mailbox = Maildir/
```

And her is my `master.cf`:

```
    #
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master" or
# on-line: http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html).
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (no)    (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       y       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       y       -       0       tlsproxy
#submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
#  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#smtps     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       y       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix    -    n    n    -    2    pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

**Update:**

I've configured `dovecot` and now, I can send and receive emails using [Rainloop](https://www.rainloop.net/), but still can not connect any client to my email.

the server refuses connection to 456 and 587, and my iPhone Mail says `logins are disabled for domain` (I tried ports 25, 143 and 110)

here is my new `main.cf`:

```
      # See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


  # Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
  # line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
  # is /etc/mailname.
  #myorigin = /etc/mailname

  smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
  biff = no

  # appending .domain is the MUA's job.
  append_dot_mydomain = no

  # Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
  #delay_warning_time = 4h

  readme_directory = no

  # TLS parameters
  smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
  smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
  smtpd_use_tls=yes
  smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
  smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

  # See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
  # information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

  smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
  myhostname = webgo.ir
  alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
  alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
  myorigin = /etc/mailname
  mydestination = webgo.ir, localhost.localdomain, localhost
  relayhost = 
  mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 137.74.154.133/32
  mailbox_command = 
  mailbox_size_limit = 0
  recipient_delimiter = +
  inet_interfaces = all
  inet_protocols = all
  home_mailbox = Maildir/
  smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
  smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
  smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
  smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The howto that you followed gives you a very basic setup. What you probably want is to use SASL to do authenticated smtp (Either port 587 or 465). That is perfect for email clients like Thunderbird.
With your current setup you can configure webmail software like Squirrelmail or Roundcube, and that would work, but adding SASL is probably what you want.
You can continue using Courier imap/pop3 but I would highly recommend to switch to Dovecot instead. 
Dovecot is really great imap/pop3 server software.

Here is Ubuntu help for SASL with Dovecot and Postfix :

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixDovecotSASL

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/postfix.html

This howto for Dovecot, Postfix, with SASL looks very good,
to start with :

http://www.binarytides.com/install-postfix-dovecot-debian

Comment: thanks for your answer , I'll post your answer when I get any result.

Comment: I can now send and recieve with Rainloop but still can't use any cline, I'll update my question for more information

Comment: In your first question you showed your Postfix master.cf file, which showed that both Submission and Smtps were not in use. Did you enable that now ? Can you show your current master.cf ? And what about firewalls ? Do you have a firewall in use on your server ? And from your local computer at home or work you are allowed to use the outgoing ports 465 and 587 ?

Comment: I've found the problem, it was because the clients must be authenticated but dovecot rejects the unauthenticated users, thank you.